# SQL: Get all missing date records from database

Tags: php, sql, database, gaps-and-islands

I have a DB table with the following structure

```
id | dateCreated | numOfUsers
```

Where a typical row is 1, '2011-10-13 12:00:00', 4

My row contains data for the last 4 months, however quite a few days are missing and i'd like to find out using SQL the missing days, any ideas how I go about writing this query?

I'd suspect you go about this by somehow getting a list of days and comparing these against the values in the database.

I know you can do this using PHP or other programming language using multiple queries however I'd like to do this on the database level if possible.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please tag your question with the appropriate database, not all of them...

Comment: Different databases, different answers -- pick one though there's numerous duplicates on SO.

Answer (score 2):

For PostgreSQL generating the "list of dates" on the fly is quite easy using the generate_series() function:

```
with all_dates as (
   select cast((current_date - interval '4' month) as date) + i as the_date
   from generate_series(0, extract(day from current_date - (current_date - interval '4' month))::int) as i
) 
select ad.the_date, 
       y.id,
       y.numOfUsers
from all_dates t
  left join your_table y ON y.dateCreated = t.the_date;
```

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK there is not one statements to achieve this working for all databases... for Oracle you can do this (`MyTable` is the DB table you want to check for missing Dates):

```
SELECT * FROM
(
SELECT A.MinD + MyList.L TheDate FROM
(SELECT  MIN (dateCreated ) MinD FROM MyTable) A,
(SELECT LEVEL - 1 L FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= (SELECT  Max (dateCreated ) - MIN (dateCreated ) + 1 FROM MyTable)) MyList
) D WHERE D.TheDate NOT IN ( SELECT dateCreated FROM MyTable T)
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming MySQL, you can use a variable to carry state through each row in the query results:

```
SELECT @last := 'date you want to start with';

SELECT id, dateCreated, DATE_DIFF(dateCreated, @last) AS diff, @last := dateCreated
FROM yourtable
ORDER BY dateCreated ASC
HAVING diff > 1
```

Note that this won't return the actual missing days, but it WILL return the rows AFTER the missing dates, as well as the count of missing days.

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to do it without a date table, start and end dates or any other form of iteration.

```
select DATEADD(day,1,left.dateCreated) as MissingDates
from dbo.MyTable as left
left outer join dbo.MyTable as right on DATEADD(day,1,left.dateCreated) = right.entry_time
where right.dateCreated is null
```

This will return a column of start dates for spans of missing dates. You can then also create another column that returns the last date in the span of missing dates by subtracting 1 instead of adding one day to the second comparison table.

Answer (score 0):

Easily the most effective way (in my opinion) is, as you state, to start with a table of all dates.  You would have to create that yourself, and assuming you have done, here are a couple of options for you...

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  calendar    -- Your manually created table of dates
LEFT JOIN
  yourTable
    ON yourTable.DateField = calendar.DateField
WHERE
  yourTable.DateField IS NULL
  AND calendar.DateField >= @reportFirstDate
  AND calendar.DateField <= @reportLastdate
```

Or...

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  calendar    -- Your manually created table of dates
WHERE
  NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM yourTable WHERE yourTable.DateField = calendar.DateField)
  AND calendar.DateField >= @reportFirstDate
  AND calendar.DateField <= @reportLastdate
```

**EDIT**

Although it can feel 'untidy' maintaining this list of dates, it has Massive performance benefits for this type of query.

With the dates table you're looking at two indexes and check for what exists in one but not another.

Without the dates table you have a much more complex approach...
1. Take every record in the table
2. Self Join it to the Next record in the table
3. If they are consecutive dates, discard them (Keeping records with a gap between them)
4. For every pair, loop through, filling in the missing dates
5. Deal with dates missing at the start of your reporting period  (No Date1 in the pairs)
6. Deal with dates missing at the  end  of your reporting period  (No Date2 in the pairs)

It's probably actually faster to create a temp table with the dates, at do it the straight forward way, then delete the table again.  And if that's the case, why wouldn't you just maintain the dates table?

1. Just have a 100 year table, and forget about it
2. Have a very quick bit of code to keep the dates up to date in all your code

If you're not convinced, I'd recommend trialling the different options and seeing for yourself just how much faster the indexed dates table is compared ot the other options.

(Not to mention how much shorter, readable and maintainable)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, however i dont like the idea of a table full of calendar days, as this means i will have to update the table every so often with the new days that are not in the calendar.

Comment: Google create date dimension, you'll find any number of scripts that'll build a table of dates for you based on a start and an end date. You can populate it with the next 20 years if you want.

Comment: SQL is a SET based language.  To find entities that exist in one set but not another, `in a way that is friendly to SQL`, you need both sets to exist.  The overhead of creating this table is tiny compared to the alternative approaches.  (One day costs 4 or 8 bytes usually, so about a quarter of a megabyte for 100 years of dates...)

Comment: ... and one could easily write a function that cycles through a date range and inserts a record for each day. Just run this as the first step in the cycle. I don't know any way to create such a list with ANSI SQL, though any given SQL dialect might have extensions to do it -- Horse mentions such an extension for Postgres, must admit I'm not familiar with it.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL:

assuming we have table `yourTable` and date field `d`:

```
set @day = 0;

select v.y as `month`, v.m as `month`, v.d as `day`
from 
(
   select y_m.y, Y_m.m, dd.d
   from
   (
     select distinct year(d) y, month(d) m, DAY(LAST_DAY(yourTable.d)) max_days from yourTable
   ) y_m,
   (
   select  @day := @day+1 as `d`
   from
     information_schema.tables
   limit 32
   ) dd
   where y_m.max_days >= dd.d
) v
left join
   yourTable on (year(yourTable.d) = v.y and month(yourTable.d) = v.m and day(yourTable.d) = v.d)
where yourTable.d is null
;
```